# Trapped with this language. Answering with 'yes' OR 'no' is not working!

Tags: negation

This is a trap. How is it possible that putting 'yes' or 'no' does not change the meaning of the sentence?

> _________, I don't have brain (yes/no) 
>  __________, I'm not a man (yes/no)

Is it grammatically wrong? If not, why the **meanings remain the same** by putting **two extremely opposite options**.

Comment: Good one Sir, as always!

Comment: I'm a man, *ain't I'? Or "aren't I"? Also, can you write this as an answer (with some more information). It is nice @FumbleFingers

Comment: [done](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57322/126)

Comment: This could be interesting: http://theweek.com/articles/451975/problem-positive-answers-negative-questions.

Comment: Related: [“No, I didn't see him” vs “Yes, I didn't see him”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24531/3281).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the explicit assertions in the examples are both effectively *denials* (expressed in *negated* form), standard usage would precede the assertion with ***No***.

This principle applies even if you're actually *agreeing* with someone - as in, for example,...

> *"You're such a coward! You're not a man at all, are you?"
>
>    "You're quite right. **No**, I'm not a man. I'm just a mouse"*

...where it would be unusual/confusing to use ***Yes*** in the highlighted position.

It's the opposite of how "question tags" work (if the assertion is positive, the tag is negative, and vice-versa). Thus *I **don't** have a brain, **do I**?* and *I'm **not** a man, **am I**?*, as opposed to *I have a brain, **don't I**?* and *I'm a man, **aren't I**?*

Comment: I'll wait for more to come. This i the answer anyway. Will tick this later. Thanks and +1

Comment: @Damkerng's [comment link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57321/trapped-with-this-language-answering-with-yes-or-no-is-not-working/57322#comment108991_57321) is interesting from a historical perspective. Plus it may be useful to NNS of languages like French, where ***Oui*** and ***Si*** still reflect some elements of ***Yes*** and ***Yea*** in archaic English, To some extent, I think ***Okay*** can effectively carry the "positive, confirmatory" implication *I agree* even when preceding a negated assertion as in mine and OP's examples.