# "...right" how should I answer to this kind to question?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

> You don't like me, right?-- the question

If I don't like him, should I say "Yes, I don't like you" or "No, I don't like you"? Which one is correct?

> (1)You like me, don't you?
>   (2)You don't like me, do you?

When I encounter these kinds of questions, I know I should say "Yes, I like you" or "No, I don't like you." in response to (1) and say "Yes, I like you" or "No, I don't like you." in response to (2).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: See ["No, I didn't see him" vs "Yes, I didn't see him"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24531/no-i-didnt-see-him-vs-yes-i-didnt-see-him).

Answer (score 1):

By saying "right?" the asker wants to get admission. If you say "yes" you have admitted his sentence, and if you say 'no' you haven't.

"Yes, I don't like you". or "No, I like you"